# Whenever I walk I get random slowdowns as though I'm clipping into the ground or encumbered

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing Skyrim Special Edition on Steam for a while now and here. Lately I've noticed my move speed slowing way down while walking.
There seem to be two stages to it (three if you count it not happening at all): at first it's hardly noticeable and I walk at maybe 80-90% speed, then, after playing for a seemingly random amount of time (ranging from a few minutes to hours), it drops without warning to like 10% of the regular speed.
Once a stage has been reached it is continuous and can't be reverted to the original speed.

I move at normal speed in the air while jumping. I'm not encumbered and can fast travel, but this is because I greatly increased my carry weight via console command at the start of the game (using `player.modav carryweight 9999` to get it to persist), so I've got around 20,000 carry capacity.

I've tried a number of fixes which didn't solve my issue:

- Saving and reloading
- Saving and quitting and loading
- I tried the recommended console command from a steam thread `player.setav speedmult 100`
- I tried testing with `tgm` and `tcl` on, both separately and together
- I tried the fixes of sprinting and talking to someone, sprinting and sitting in a chair
- I've dumped enough stuff in chests and whatnot to be at around 4,000 of 20,000 carry weight, and it still didn't help.
- I've also tried emptying my inventory of everything but quest items (0 carry weight) and it still persisted.

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure this out.

---

Mod list:

```
- 100 percent max pickpocket chance
- AchievementsModsEnablerSSE
- Alchemist Compendium
- Andromeda - unique standing stones of Skyrim
- Angelic Halos and Demonic Horns
- Ars Metallica
- Ash Pile Expiration SE Installer
- Auto hide ammo
- Barenziah quest makers
- BetterConsoleV20
- Breezehome - Eli's Breezehome Overhaul
- Craftable unarmored and armored vampire gear
- Dark Brotherhood Reborn - Dawnstar Sanctuary
- Dark Envoy 
- Death Alternative - Your money or your life
- Disenchantable Dark Brotherhood gear
- DisplayEnemyLevelSE
- Dragon Wall Wisdom - Readable Dragon Walls
- Eli_Breezehome - Ars Metallica Patch
- Enchant and smithing potion duration
- Fangs and eyes - Red Combat
- Fast travel from interiors
- Fortify destruction damage
- Fortify enchanting
- Fully improvable Nightingale armor
- GIST Soul Trap
- Hearthfire Multiple adoptions and custom home support SE
- Hearthfire mod that makes my kids' last names Dovahkiir (can't find the exact name)
- Hide-SkyUI
- Holidays
- Hot springs of Skyrim
- Hunterborn
- Immersive Children SE - FOMOD installer
- Immersive citizens - AI overhaul
- Immersive speechcraft SE
- Jewelry limiter - another multiple rings and amulets mod
- Leveled vampire drain - legendary edition
- Marry me Serana
- Mirai the Girl with the Dragon Heart
- Modern Brawl Bug Fix
- Neko race - all in one installer
- No Camera Collision
- RaceCompatibility All-in-One Scripted Installer
- RaceMenu
- Raeza - Adoptable Plugin
- Raeza SE (main file)
- Readable Shadowmarks
- Resurrect
- Scaling Bound Weapons
- Sig. Equip.
- SkyUI
- SKSE64 (Skyrim Script Extender for Special Edition)
- Spell Crafting for Skyrim
- The Paarthurnax dilemma
- The Shrouded Lair
- The Shrouded Lair Expansion
- Thieves Guild Bounty Clearer
- Truly Light Glass Armor
- Truly Light Glass Armor no pauldrons (both the standalone version)
- UnenchantedItems
- Unlimited Training
- UNP Female Body Renewal
- Unread books glow SSE
- Vampire Lord no fall damage
- Vampire Lords can activate
- Vampires regen
- Viewable faction ranks
- Volkihar Knight SE
- White River Cottage SE
- Wintersun
```

---

## Update:

It looks like the issue might have to do with my controller as I had an identical issue in another game as well (Killing Floor 2). Will test with a new controller soon and update with the results.

Comment: What are the results if you empty your inventory completely? (0 carry weight)

Comment: @Zymus Haven't tried that, I'll try it tonight after work (so in like 2-3 hours) and update you then

Comment: Sounds good. I vaguely remember some separate calculation that affects movement speed/carry capacity based on the stamina you have, maybe evaluated after every level up, but can't recall for sure.

Comment: If it's based on stamina I should mention that I have about 300 stamina

Comment: Slowing down how? Whenever you start walking, the speed with which you do just decreases? Is this continuous, do you at some point get to a complete halt?

Comment: Could it be that one of the mods you have interferes with the setting of your walking speed, it could also be a multitude of mods not working properly with each other

Comment: @Joachim not quite a complete stop but I'd say about 10% of normal walking speed. I've also tried emptying my inventory of everything but quest items (0 carry weight) and it still persisted. It's continuous in the sense of once it start it doesn't stop but ti's not like it gets progressively worse. There seem to be 2 stages to it though (3 if you count it not happening at all). At first it's hardly noticeable and I walk at maybe 80-90% speed then after playing for a while it drops without warning to like 10% speed

Comment: @Wouter I don't believe any of the mods I have installed would make any changes to walking speed. And as far as I know, none of the installed mods should have any conflicts with each other either.

Comment: Two more questions: 1. once you've reach 10% of the speed, and you stop your character, do you start out with the regular speed again, or do you need to reload/restart the game? 2. Can you give an estimate about the time intervals those stages occur (and are they always of the same duration)?

Comment: @Joachim Once I hit the 10% speed and I stop completely I can start walking again and I start out still at the 10% speed and none of the fixes I've tried have been able to remedy it even temporarily. I can't give an estimate because it's inconsistant. Sometimes it takes a few minutes to get from 100% to 10% other times it takes a few hours to even get to 80-90%

Comment: Once you've reached a lower speed, can you put in the command `player.getAV carryweight` and tell us what the output? Is it still the `9999` or has it changed?

Comment: I can test that after work tonight. But I will say in the meantime that I've checked my inventory and my carry capacity has not changed. (ran the command twice so my actual carry capacity is a little over over 20,000) so I don't *think* that command will output anything different but I will check tonight to be sure

Comment: Also would it be worth checking on that if even after the speed drops the game still doesn't considered me encumbered to the degree that I can't fast travel?

Comment: That command doesn't check the current weight you're carrying, rather the current limit. I think the problem might lie with 'random' changes to that value. If the value has indeed changed, it will hint towards the underlying problem. So affirmative of your last comment, yesh!

Comment: Tested it last night and got some interesting results. Firstly, that command still read the same as what my carry weight limit shows in my inventory. Secondly, the issue only seems to exist when walking _forward_. I walked sideways at one point and was at full speed. I haven't been able to test if this was coincidence or not but I mounted a horse, rode a bit, got off and used unrelenting force on a group of enemies and noticed my speed was back to normal and persisted for the rest of the session that night.

Comment: And if your carry weight is below the vanilla value, does the problem still persist?

Comment: @Joachim the issue persisted at a 0 carry weight too. However it seems to have resolved itself after Fus Roh Dah'ing a group of enemies off a cliff and mounting a horse.

Comment: Permanently? That's really strange. Oh well, I'm glad it solved itself, in a way.

Comment: @Joachim indeed it is. If this issue pops back up and this (really strange) fix doesn't work I'll update the question again.

Comment: Be sure to post your update as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched out my controller for a new one that as far as I can tell is physically identical and the issue seems to have passed so I can only assume that it had something to do with that one. Both controllers are Xbox One controllers (will edit with the brand name tomorrow) with a removable micro USB cord to connect to the computer. I used the same cord for both controllers.

Comment: Do you know if it was a physical problem or one related to Skyrim's controller support?

Comment: Leaning toward physical due to the fact that it happened in another game as well @Joachim

Comment: That would also account for the decrease in speed. Can you add what kind of controller you have to your answer for future reference and increased findability?

Comment: @Joachim I've added that info. Any other info you think I should add?

Comment: No, I think that's good. Thanks!